# Tree Traversal examples

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have this binary tree here, can anyone confirm if the order I have for post, pre, and in order traversals are correct? If not, can you example the process? Thanks

```
                        20
                      /    \
                   15     28
                  /   \
                7     16
               /         \
              5         19

Left subtree, right subtree, then root node.
postOrder: 5 7 19 16 15 28 20

Root node visited first, then left and right subtree's.
preOrder:   20 15 7 5 16 19 28

Left subtree visited first, then the root, then right subtree.
inOrder:    5 7 15 16 19 20 28
```

Answer (score 1):

*Pre-order traversal*: visit root, visit left node, visit right child node. **Yours is correct**.

*In-order traversal*: visit left node, visit root, visit right node. **Yours is correct**.

*Post-order traversal*: visit left node, visit right node, visit root. **Yours is correct**.

Nice work!